# ReactJS Set Selected Option based on Prop Text Match

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get query parameters from my url and use those values to set the selected option value on load. At the moment I have access to two values that match, which are the option text and the query parameter value.

My original thought is to add a variable within my loop that is set by an if statement that checks if the loop value matches the query props value, but I'm being given an error message about an unexpected token. What is possibly wrong with this setup and there is a better way to set up this evaluation and set "select" to the proper option on page load?

Here is the full error message (`{selected}` is where the error happens):

```
ERROR in ./public/components/app/activity-feed/search-form.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ... (45:102)

  43 |                                                         selected = 'selected';
  44 |                                                     }
> 45 |                                                     return ( <option value={category.categoryHashId} {selected}>
```

Here is my react code where `this.props.category` is an array of ids/text for each category that is possible to query and `this.props.categoryQuery` is the text value that is currently a query parameter:

```
<select name="category" className="form-control filter-category">
    { this.props.category.map( (category) => { var selected; if(category.categoryName == this.props.categoryQuery){ selected = 'selected'; } return (
    <option value={category.categoryHashId} {selected}>{category.categoryName}</option> ) } ) }
</select>
```

For example, `this.props.categoryQuery` is `Blog` and out of the 8 `this.props.category.categoryName` array values, `Blog` matches and a "selected" string is added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** write a prop for an element the way you are doing: `<tag {someValue}/>`.

Instead, pass a `value` property to the `select` element and a `defaultValue` to the `option` elements:

```
const {
    category,
    categoryQuery
} = this.props;
const selectedCategory = category.find((val) => {
    return val.categoryName === categoryQuery;
})

return (
    <select
        name="category"
        className="form-control filter-category"
        value={selectedCategory.categoryHashId}
    >
        {category.map((cat) => {
            return (
                <option
                    key={cat.categoryHashId}
                    defaultValue={cat.categoryHashId}
                >
                    {cat.categoryName}
                </option>
            );
        })}
    </select>
);
```

**Sidenote**: You should not use the `categoryName` for identification/comparison/selection if you have a unique `categoryHashId`. When the user selects the category, use this instead of the name. You might want to review a bit your data structure for more efficiency.

I wrote this example to match your need, but if you use a `hashId` inside your `categoryQuery` you can skip the `.find()` step.

Comment: That works, but I see a warning related to this solution `Warning: Use the 'defaultValue' or 'value' props on <select> instead of setting 'selected' on <option>.`. Is there a better option based on this warning?

Comment: Updated code for warning, tell me if that answers it.